How to recover data from an unfinalized DVD?
I've been trying to recover some old family photos and videos that I have stored on a DVD+R for a while now. Although it shows that there is almost no space left on the disk, when I open it, it appears to be empty. After doing some research, I found out that it might be unfinalized.
I used a software called IMGBurn to run a disc analysis. That is what I found out:
Current Profile: DVD+R

Disc Information:
Status: Incomplete
State of Last Session: Empty
Erasable: No
Sessions: 2
Sectors: 2,255,504
Size: 4,619,272,192 bytes
Time: 501:15:29 (MM:SS:FF)
Free Sectors: 37,552
Free Space: 76,906,496 bytes
Free Time: 08:22:52 (MM:SS:FF)
Next Writable Address: 2257552
MID: RITEK-F16-01
Supported Read Speeds: 2.4x, 4x, 6x, 8x, 12x, 16x
Current Read Speed: 2.4x

TOC Information:
Session 1... (LBA: 0)
-> Track 01  (Mode 1, LBA: 0 - 2255503)
-> LeadOut  (LBA: 2255504)

Track Information:
Session 1...
-> Track 01 (LTSA: 0, LTS: 2255504, LRA: 0)

Disc Control Blocks Information:
HL-DT-ST GSA-T10N

Physical Format Information (ADIP):
Disc ID: RITEK-F16-01
Book Type: DVD+R
Part Version: 1
Disc Size: 120 mm
Maximum Read Rate: Not Specified
Number of Layers: 1
Track Path: Parallel Track Path (PTP)
Linear Density: 0.267 um/bit
Track Density: 0.74 um/track
First Physical Sector of Data Area: 196,608
Last Physical Sector of Data Area: 2,491,711
Last Physical Sector in Layer 0: 0

Physical Format Information (Last Recorded):
Disc ID: RITEK-F16-01
Book Type: DVD+R
Part Version: 1
Disc Size: 120 mm
Maximum Read Rate: Not Specified
Number of Layers: 1
Track Path: Parallel Track Path (PTP)
Linear Density: 0.267 um/bit
Track Density: 0.74 um/track
First Physical Sector of Data Area: 196,608
Last Physical Sector of Data Area: 2,491,711
Last Physical Sector in Layer 0: 0

Do you know some ways to finalize the DVD or recover the data from it?
Thank you.

There are a few answers posted, e.g., https://superuser.com/questions/148647/how-to-read-old-non-finalized-cds, https://superuser.com/questions/262280/empty-dvd-but-supposedly-contains-a-backup-how-to-diagnose, https://superuser.com/questions/1838196/why-does-a-dvd-rw-with-data-on-it-show-as-empty

Do you know which software wrote this DVD?
